# StringBuilder + link

Tags: asp.net-mvc, string

I have this code

```
public string DeletedMessage(int id) { 
            StringBuilder query= new StringBuilder();
            query.AppendLine("test");
            query.AppendLine("");

            query.AppendLine("test - "+"http://test.com/test/"+id);

            return query.ToString();
        }
```

And this link comes to as a string and not a link, How can i add link to StringBuilder line ?

Comment: What result do you expect? Do you want an <a> tag in your string? Or doesn't your string render correctly in MVC?

Comment: yes i need <a> tag in my string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create tags by using the `TagBuilder` class in MVC. This class helps you in setting attributes and the inner text on a new tag. In your case, you are looking for an `<a>` tag that creates a hyperlink for you.

You can modify your `DeletedMessage` method like this:

```
public string DeletedMessage(int id)
{
    StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
    query.AppendLine("test");
    query.AppendLine();

    TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("a");
    tagBuilder.SetInnerText("http://test.com/test/");
    tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("src", "http://test.com/test/" + id);

    query.AppendLine("test - " + tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));

    return query.ToString();
}
```